# Add a bit in the middle of any two bits

Tags: bit-manipulation

In a binary representation of a number is there a simpler way than this

```
    long half(long patten, bool exclusive) {
        if (patten == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        long newPatten = 0;
        for (int p = 0; p < MAX_STEPS; p++) {
            long check = 1 << p;
            if ((check & patten) > 0) {
                int end = (p + MAX_STEPS) - 1;
                for (int to = p+1; to <= end; to++) {
                    long checkTo = 1 << (to % MAX_STEPS);
                    if ( (checkTo & patten) > 0 || to == end ) {
                        int distance = to - p;
                        long fullShift = (int)round( ((float)p) + ((float)distance)/2 );
                        long shift = fullShift % MAX_STEPS;
                        long toAdd = 1 << shift;
                        newPatten = newPatten | toAdd;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return exclusive ? patten ^ newPatten : patten | newPatten;
     }
```

To add a bit in the middle of any two other bits with wrapping around and rounding to one side when there is an even number of positions between?

E.g.

010001 to
110101

Or

1001 to
1101

Update: These bits aren't coming from anywhere else, such as another number, just want a new True bit to be in the middle of any other two True bits, so if there was a 101, then the middle would be the 0 and the result would be 111. Or if we started with 10001, then the middle  would be the center 0 and the result would be 10101.

When i say wrapping i also mean adding bits as if the bit array was a circle so if we had 00100010 representing the positions with letters:

```
00100010
hgfedcba
```

So we have True bits at `b` and `f` we would put a middle bit between `b` and `f` going left to right at `d` but also going right to left, wrapping around and putting it at `h` resulting in:

```
10101010
hgfedcba
```

I understand this isn't a usual problem.

Are there known tricks to do things like this without loops?

Comment: mask, shift, and add. That said: care to explain where in your example "from" values you "added" a bit? because it doesn't look like you added anything just a single bit somewhere in 010001 to get to 110101 (and remember to edit your post text to make that clearer, don't just respond in a comment)

Comment: If you mean "insert" a bit and push the other bits right or left then for  `010001 to 110101` shouldn't there only be 3 `1` bits?

Comment: Added some updates to hopefully clear up these questions

Comment: so in when 010001 → 110101 where do you get the top bit from? and when there are an even number of bits between two 1 bits then do you always set the left bit like in 1001 → 1101? So 100001 → 101001?